# Is there a robust, free module for SE-style social signup?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I want to enable users to create accounts using existing Google, Facebook etc accounts, without needing to come up with and remember yet another password. Similar to how the StackExchange network does.

There's a proliferation of modules that have related features to these. I'd like to know if there's any one of them which has proven to be stable, robust, simple (requiring few dependencies or possible points of failure) and working without requiring paid subscriptions.

---

**Some modules I've looked at:**

- I've seen many recommendations for [Janrain Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/rpx), but I read that it's a paid-for service. This site is a very small project and that's beyond its scope. The demos I've seen also suggest that it removes the ability to create a Drupal-only account should the user want to.
- I tried the built-in OpenID module plus [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect), but discovered that it only supports log in, not sign up.
- There's a stack of modules built around [OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth) (e.g. [OAuth Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauthconnector)). I gather that OAuth is a different protocol to OpenID, and requires dependencies to be installed on the server. In terms of functionality I haven't yet figured out what the fundamental difference is between the OAuth stack and Drupal's built-in OpenId stack, and I can't find any confirmation in the various docs available that it does indeed support signups. It has all the hallmarks of a serious project, though.
- There's the [connector module](https://www.drupal.org/project/connector) - I think this an API module used by the OAuth stack?
- [Hybrid Auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) looks really promising and is **my current front-runner**: it explicitly supports signup and login, and has minimal dependencies (one open-source library, `php-curl`, and ctools), and is under active development with a stable D7 release. Sounds great, but I've not seen many recommendations for it, so I'm wondering if there's something I've overlooked.
- There's [Gigya](https://www.drupal.org/project/gigya), which looks like a 3rd-party service with fancy social features that aren't relevant in my case.
- There's [OneAll social login](https://www.drupal.org/project/social-login), which has a promising-sounding description but doesn't appear to be widely used.
- There's [Social Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_connect), but it seems to be Facebook only.
- ...and loads more, including many more 3rd party services and modules for specific providers.

I'd appreciate any expert advice from experience on the simplest stable way to get a sign up screen similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used Hybrid Auth . It works well. I tried anothers. They were not so good. Yes,  Hybrid Auth does not have another functionality to share content. But It should not have it. It uses the separated library. It does not use third party services. It's free and independent.

If you tell me your successful experience with another libraries I will be pleased.